# Enumerate through binary number bits in reverse

Tags: javascript, binary

I currently have this loop that takes an integer and prints out 0 or 1 for each bit of it's binary version.

```
var m = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  bit = m & 1;
  console.log(bit ? + 1 : 0 );
  m >>= 1;
}
```

This results in 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

How can I get it to loop in reverse? 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate a bit mask rather than shifting bits of the integer.

```
for (var i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    bit = m & (1 << i);
    console.log(bit ? 1 : 0);
}
```

or:

```
for (var mask = 1 << 7; mask; mask >>= 1) {
    bit = m & mask;
    console.log(bit ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Note that in some browsers the console does not print a log if the message is the same as the last one, so you must look at "repeated n times" for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to hand-craft the whole binary representation implementation, then you can use [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071847/1903116).

But, the good news is, there is a reliable, builtin function, [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) which you can use to do this, like this

```
var bin = (10).toString(2), numberOfBits = 8;
console.log((new Array(numberOfBits + 1).join("0") + bin).slice(bin.length));
```

**Output**

```
00001010
```

Comment: I am unsure of the length - 8 in my ex - so I would have to use binary string padding functions for this

Comment: @Yashua You can customize this answer, just like you want :)